# Pointer to member expression UB

Tags: c++, class

The Standard `N3797::5.5/4`:

> Abbreviating `pm-expression.*cast-expression` as `E1.*E2`, `E1` is called
>   the object expression. *If the dynamic type of E1 does not contain the*
>   *member to which `E2` refers, the behavior is undefined*

Could you provide an example produces UB described here?

Comment: At runtime `E1` might not have a member `E2`, if it was an object of a base class for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the actual type of `E1` at runtime doesn't have a member `E2`. A simple case would happen when `E1` is an instance of a base class of the type that actually has a member `E2`.

```
struct A
{
};

struct B : public A
{
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);
    int B::* pbm = &B::b;
    (*b).*pbm = 6;
}
```

Comment: The result of the cast itself is UB, regardless of the question